# VC 2008 error, old lib file, need to rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction

Hello everyone first of all thank you for all your answers and i am sorry for taking your time.
 I got small problem with my client side, project isn't mine but when i tried to compile it. I get an error which says: "...you need to compile lib in new version, becouse it is compiled in old one.", k i got those errors on all projects and fixed them all.
 But this one when i replace the new builded 'lib' file in needed location it says the same thing? 
Why, even when i rebuild this 'lib' i still receive the same error and only on that one project? Tried testing location. I deleted the file from where it should receive then i got error can't open file, k. It means the location is fine, i rebuilded the file like i did to fix the same error with other projects, it rebuilded succesfully changed in the location, k. Then thinked about some tool->options problem didin't find anything fishy. k, still it shows me this error?

P.S i tried reinstalling vc, yes i am using sp 1 and have some updates on it. :)
Will be back in hour.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build configuration to make sure that the project is using the same configuration for the library as for the other projects.  When you create a new project configuration in a VC solution and change your current project to that configuration, projects that don't have that configuration will not change, and VC won't necessarily create one for you.

Comment: Nope the problem isn't there or maybe i didin't find the right location where to check if configurations are good or bad.